# NSWindow setFrame not working in Lion?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I've been killing myself over this issue in Cocoa and Lion and was wondering if anyone has come across this issue and (hopefully) found a solution.

I've got a very simple project (code can be downloaded here: http://cl.ly/2T0N2C1A3K1r2h1q0R1e ) where a NSWindowController assigns the position of a window using the setFrameOrigin: method on an NSWindow.

On first run this works A-OK, but once the user moves the window, quits & restarts the app the window restores it's previous location instead of employing the setFrameOrigin: command.

The NSWindowController already has cascade and autosave disabled so it *shouldn't* be happening.

Also, i've tested on Snow Leopard and the code works 100% - it's a Lion only issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's Lion's "User Interface Preservation" feature, which is documented in the  [App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html)

The simple solution is to uncheck "Restorable" in the window's attributes pane.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that letting window restoration do its thing wouldn't be appropriate in actual usage as opposed to debugging. To turn it off for debugging only, uncheck it in your Xcode scheme.

Comment: Where'd that option come from!? :P
That fixed it 100%.

Comment: Great answer—ludicrous problem.